# upload image in PHP5

Tags: image-uploading, php-5.5

I have this code in PHP to upload images to directory. The problem is: It's not uploading .png files.

Error: Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!

I don't know how to fix, already tried a lot of changes.

```
 <?php
        //Upload de arquivos
        // verifica se foi enviado um arquivo
        if(isset($_FILES['arquivo']['name']) && $_FILES["arquivo"]["error"] == 0)
        {
            echo "Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['name'] . "</strong><br />";
            echo "Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['type'] . "</strong><br />";
            echo "Temporáriamente foi salvo em: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'] . "</strong><br />";
            echo "Seu tamanho é: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['size'] . "</strong> Bytes<br /><br />";

            $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
            $nome = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

            // Pega a extensao
            $extensao = strrchr($nome, '.');

            // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
            $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

            // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
            // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
            // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
            if(strstr('.jpg;.png;.gif;.jpeg', $extensao))
            {
                // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
                // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
                $novoNome = md5(microtime()) . $extensao;

                // Concatena a pasta com o nome
                $destino = 'images/uploads/logos/' . $novoNome;

                // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
                if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
                {
                    echo "Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>" . $destino . "</strong><br />";
                    echo '<img src="' . $destino . '" />';
                    echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/administracao">';
                    exit;
                }
                else
                    echo "Erro ao salvar o arquivo. Aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita.<br />";
            }
            else
                echo "Você poderá enviar apenas arquivos .jpg, .jpeg, .gif e .png.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!";
        }
    ?>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Can I see your html code, please?

Comment: I've edited my question and added html code. Thank you

Comment: Since this line triggers `echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";` I assume the file copy did not succeed. Are you sure PHP has no errors? `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting( E_ALL );`

Comment: Same message errors above

Comment: I have a few tips: 1) Check the file path 2) Check if the file does not already exsist on the server 3) Check whether the input file name does not contain bad-characters (also strip dangerous characters and such). *) offtopic hint: Check the file types, you don't want virus infections.

Comment: Hey, check it please Xyv

Comment: What is the message you're getting? All of the variables and messages written in Portuguse doesn't really help... Also like I said, check the MIMEtypes of the files, not the extentions. Someone can easily rename a bat, exe, sh, etc to .png. A mime type makes it slightly more difficult to cheat the system.

Comment: Had any success lately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking if the string after `.` matches your accepted extensions. Like I mentioned in the comment section a user can easily change their file's extension and upload it regardless of the content.

On PHP.net there is an article/comment about how to upload files, some safety issues are also explained briefly in code and solved. I think this part will do for you:

```
// DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
// Check MIME Type by yourself.
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if (false === $ext = array_search(
    $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
    array(
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
    ),
    true
)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.'); // You can replace this with a custom message if you want. 
                                                        // Either that or catch it in higher level
}
```

[*Source to this code (PHP.net)*](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004)

Also make sure that your errors are enabled, so you can spot any PHP mistakes:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);         // Report ALL errors once they occur
ini_set('display_errors', 1);   // Once they get reported, print them as HTML on your page
```

*One more suggestion, remove the [error suppression](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) `@` in the `move_uploaded_file` `if` statement. If anything fails, you won't see why.*

So I think this saves you time, as well fixing your problem in a safe way.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

some comments.

This path must have write permission.

```
$destino = 'images/uploads/logos/' . $novoNome;
```

Also check that your form has

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: I have permition and i have this enctype in html. uploading jpg works fine but png dont

Comment: if you do a `var_dump($_FILES['arquivo']['name'])` what does it shows? it seems that the file info is not being posted